# For all (loop) in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, database-schema

Good morning/day/evening

I am struggling with this SQL query in which I am supposed to find those that are 10 years older than those who they know . So I am supposed to find Woody and Sandra since both of them (Wade knows pacey and Sandra knows Pacey too) know someone who is younger than them. Also we need to know that if one person knows the other one, then they know each other. So that is why the answer is Sandra and Wade

The tables can be found  the end

Any advice on how I can tackle this problem?

Table people

```
| id | name      | age  
+----+-----------+------
| 77 | Wade      | 83 
| 78 | Pacey     | 09 
| 79 | Sandra    | 27 
| 80 | Suri      | 21
| 81 | Andrew    | 25 
| 82 | Joyce     | 04 
| 83 | Becky     | 24 
| 84 | Kevin     | 17
```

Table know

```
| id | IDpersonA | IDpersonB
+----+-----------+----------
| 105 |    78     |    79
| 106 |    80     |    79
| 107 |    77     |    80
| 108 |    79     |    77
| 109 |    79     |    78
| 110 |    77     |    79
| 111 |    79     |    77
| 112 |    80     |    78
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is on approach using `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from knows k
    inner join persons p1 on p1.id = k.idPersonB
    where p.id = k.idPersonA and p1.age > p.age
)
```

If you want to ensure that the persons in the resultset know at least one other person:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where 
    exists (select 1 from knows k where p.id = k.idPersonA)
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from knows k
        inner join persons p1 on p1.id = k.idPersonB
        where p.id = k.idPersonA and p1.age > p.age
    )
```

Comment: @Sokka: the (first) query returns Woody, Susan and Sigourney. Woody and Sigourney are older than everybody they know,and Susan knows nobody. The second query returns Woody and Sigourney.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you can use `all`:

```
select p.*
from people p
where p.age > all (select p2.age
                   from knows k join
                        people pb
                        on k.IDpersonB = pb.id
                   where k.IDpersonA = p.id
                  );
```

This will return people who do not know anyone.

You can also use aggregation in the subquery:

```
select p.*
from people p
where p.age > (select max(p2.age)
               from knows k join
                    people pb
                    on k.IDpersonB = pb.id
               where k.IDpersonA = p.id
              );
```

This is subtly different.  It requires that someone know at least one person.